How to correctly stop cursor execution and deallocate/close after there is an error?
I have a SQL cursor using which I loop over records in a table.
I'm trying to do some error handling wherein the execution should stop, and cursor closed/deallocated.
Based on my testing, if I do select 1/0; or if I RAISEERROR (level 16), then the execution continues ahead after the error, and then fetches the next recoed from the cursor and so on..
However if I place the above inside a TRY/CATCH and throw; in the CATCH, then it exists, is this correct approach and do I close/deallocate cursor in the catch block?

The absolute best way would be to stop using cursors. SQL does not do well with looping.

Use local cursor or cursor variables and you don't have to bother closing or deallocating them on batch exit. Also, SET XACT_ABORT ON; is a nice setting to have which kills batch on errors.

@siggemannen - isn't xact abort related to transactions?

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-xact-abort-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16  The THROW statement honors SET XACT_ABORT. RAISERROR does not. New applications should use THROW instead of RAISERROR.

Given that my intention is to stop execution (THROW), does it matter if I place try inside cursor OR outside cursor?
